# sticky-top header won't work for safari, why?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, header, fixed, sticky

I'm making a sticky-top header navigation with bootstrap which works fine in Chrome & Firefox. However it does not work in Safari and Mobile Safari for iPhone.

I've tried webkit-sticky prefix but that wont work.

Having a fixed-top header works, BUT, then the content will simply overlap the other and not take up any height. I don't know how to fix this without guessing the margin of the header and that seems bad.

```
<header class="sticky-top">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-dark navbar-light">
    <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" routerLink="/">MovieCore</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/movies">Movies</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Checkout</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Admin</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search movies" aria-label="Search">
        <button class="btn my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Maybe it could interrest you https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/migration/#browser-support